# Javascript: Close Modal and the focus not return to the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

I'm using modal dialog via jQuery. When I close the modal, then I can not press any key(not click by mouse). Does the element of modal dialog hold the focus event it's closed.

```
 <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" id="btn-cancel" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: @MeeneshJain Yes that's right. I can not handle the trigger or any event on the main page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future, please edit your question to include additional information, rather than posting it as answers or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it. Just set the setTimeOut for the event you want to trigger when the modal is hidden.

```
$('#modalViewNode').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        setTimeout("$('.splittable-primary').focus();", 200);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created a working [example](http://www.bootply.com/xYaPTJ3aK3).

Can you please tell us, where your code differs from the working example?

Or just post your entire code, this would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @bloC, thank for the help. i compare with your example and my code, i see nothing differs. 
Please see my code in this: http://www.bootply.com/7Qzlhrzwdg

Comment: is this all the code you have? I think at least your html is missing.

Comment: Ok @bloC. I posted my code. javascript and html. 
http://www.bootply.com/U5bNMpf4HD